# A blog sample for asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc 4 and I'm trying to create a blog from scratch to get my hands dirty. I can't see any tutorial over the internet that creates a blog from scratch using asp.net mvc 4. I saw some sample to download but I can't get it running. Also, starting from scratch would be the best way for me to learn.

Do you have any website tutorial for suggestion?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is exactly what you are looking for:

> [How to create a simple blog using ASP.NET MVC - Part I](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1)
>   [How to create a simple blog using ASP.NET MVC - Part II](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2013/3/how_to_create_simple_blog_part2)
>   [How to create a simple blog using ASP.NET MVC - Part III](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2013/6/how_to_create_simple_blog_part3)

Comment: There is one at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwmUFTWEh6Y&list=PLRmyy9vm8xSLp6_s1ok74oFVpM5aRiORM

Comment: @MaxPayne is there a blog created with EF 6 not with nhibernate?

Comment: Yes !! exactly what we are looking for !